# Google Maps v3: What is the maximum zoom level of a roadmap?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am familiar with how to use the MaxZoomService to determine the maximum zoom level for satellite imagery.  But how can I determine the maximum zoom level for the `google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP` MapType?

Or better yet, how can I determine the maximum zoom level for a given MapTypeId such as returned by `map.getMapTypeId()`?

`map.mapTypes[map.getMapTypeId()]` returns undefined, so I cannot access the `.maxZoom` property of the MapType as noted/suggested here:
[How do I detect when a user is at the maximum zoom level? (google maps v3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513417/how-do-i-detect-when-a-user-is-at-the-maximum-zoom-level-google-maps-v3)

Comment: This does not answer your question but access to base maps was intentionally disabled by Google to prevent scraping of map tiles. That is why `map.mapTypes[map.getMapTypId()]` returns undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo, it has to be:

```
map.mapTypes[map.getMapTypeId()]
//------------------------^
```

Comment: Fixed typo, thanks.  Code still does not work.

Comment: you must wait until the projection of the map is available(observe e.g. the projection_changed -event of the map), before you access it . http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/5Fuve/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read `map.mapTypes[map.getMapTypeId()]` as explained here:

> **You do not read directly from the map type registry**. Instead, you
>   modify the registry by adding custom map types and associating them
>   with a string identifier of your choosing. **You cannot modify or alter
>   the basic map types** (though you can remove them from the map by
>   altering the appearance of the map's associated mapTypeControlOptions.

Quoted from: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#BasicMapTypes